# Representation of D_{12}

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $D_{12}$ be the dihedral group, $\langle  x,y: x^2 = y^6 =1 , xy = y^{-1}x \rangle$ and $H = \langle xy \rangle$ be a subgroup.Let $\xi$ denote a representation of $D_{12}$ which sends y to rotation by $2\pi/6$ matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$  and sends $x$ to reflexion by $x$-axis.

What is $Res_{H}^{D_{12}}(\xi)$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: $<$ and $>$ are comparison operators and get corresponding spacing. To make what you were trying to write come out right, use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead, e.g. `H=\langle xy\rangle` yields $H=\langle xy\rangle$.

Comment: $xy$ is a reflection (w.r.t. a line you may want to determine as an extra). So $H$ is a cyclic group of order two. Finding the matrix of $xy$ is the only thing you need to calculate. Because $\xi$ is a representation $\xi(xy)=\xi(x)\xi(y)$, which I'm sure you can do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Actually I'm interested to understand the following thing. We know the irreducible representations of $H$ are trivial($\mathbb{1}$) and sign($\sigma$). Then how can one express $Res_{H}^{D_{12}}$ in terms of  trivial($\mathbb{1}$) and sign($\sigma$) ?

Comment: Ok. Can you justify (by looking at the action of the dihedral group on a hexagon) that $xy$ is, indeed, a reflection (as I promised). What are the eigenvalues of a plane reflection?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : eigenvalues are 1 and -1.

Comment: Correct. Therefore *trivial* and *sign* appear as summands of $Res_H^{D_{12}}(\xi)$ with multiplicities ____ and ____?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think $Res_{H}^{D_{12}}$ = $1 + \sigma$.Is it alright?

Comment: Correct again :-). For a complete geometric point of view: The line that $xy$ reflects about is a 1-dimensional trivial subrepresentation of $H$. The line perpendicular to that is also stable under that action of $H$, but the reflection obviously acts according to $\sigma$ on it. I want to encourage you to flesh all this out to an answer. That way you get more feedback, and we can wrap up this question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:Can u help me to find out $Res_{K}^{D_{12}}(\xi^2)$ ? Where $K = \{1 ,y^3 , xy , xy^3 \}$.